# Integration and plotting: How to draw Pathline?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I have function $u_x = dx/dt = 5 - (0.5y)/(x^2+y^2)$
and $u_y = dy/dt = (0.5x)/(x^2+y^2)$
and I'm trying to integrate pathline equation with respect to $t$ at reference point at $(-0.3,0)$ at $t= 0$s.

so I used integrate and contour function in *Mathematic*a, but the graph looks wrong.

Here is my try:

```
Integrate[1/(5 - (0.5*y)/(x^2 + y^2)), x]
Integrate[1/((0.5*x)/(x^2 + y^2)), y]

ContourPlot[0.2 x - (0.02 Sqrt[y] ArcTanh[(x)/Sqrt[(0.1 - y) y]])/Sqrt[0.1 - y] + 
 0.06 == (2 (x^2 y + y^3/3))/x, {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}]
```

but it gave me totally wrong graph,
Did I have correct Integrate expression?

Thanks

Comment: What you are expecting to have as an output?

Comment: I was trying to plot pathline equation by using ContourPlot function, 
but when I tried that, it gives me wrong one.

Comment: What I meant to say is that do you have an existing graph which you want to replicate in Mathematica?

Comment: No, I don't. I just know what should be the abstract shape of graph look like.

Comment: Just a hunch, try this `StreamPlot[{0.2 x - (
   0.02 Sqrt[y]
     ArcTanh[(1 x)/Sqrt[(0.1 - 1. y) y]])/Sqrt[0.1 - 1. y], (
  2. (x^2 y + y^3/3))/x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

Comment: yeah I'm looking at it right now, I think we shouldn't use SteramPlot since it gives all possible stream lines, not just one

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong with this `ContourPlot[{0.2 x - (0.02 Sqrt[
        y] ArcTanh[(1 x)/Sqrt[(0.1 - 1. y) y]])/
     Sqrt[0.1 - 1. y] == (2. (x^2 y + y^3/3))/x}, {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, 
  0, 0.3}]. Do you?`

Comment: Thank you for your help M.
I think pathline plot should be single smooth line on the region,
but what I'm seeing is that various random lines.
In addition, the line should be passed the point (-0.3,0) 
Isn't it?

Comment: When I change to `{y, 0, 0.3}` then I see a single smooth line. Don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = Integrate[1/(5 - (0.5*y)/(x^2 + y^2)), x];
b = Integrate[1/((0.5*x)/(x^2 + y^2)), y];
ContourPlot[{a == b}, {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, 0.1001, 0.18}]
```

[image]